# On QTreeView double_Clicked event: how to know which folder was clicked?

Tags: c++, qt, treeview

I'm still pretty new to C++ and qt creator. I have a TreeView displaying a directory, and upon double-clicking a folder I'd like to be able to get the directory of the folder, so i can do something with the contents. I notice the `double_Clicked` event passing along a "`const QModelIndex& index`" and I suppose this holds some information on which folder of the tree was clicked. I can't find any documentation on this signal, and what the "`index`" passed along could be. Does anyone have an explanation, tutorial, example, documentation, ... for me? I've been searching for awhile and trying things out but I can't find the solution. Or additionally: how can I check what gets passed along? How could I print this, or know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up your treeView in the constructor like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    model = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    model->setRootPath("");
    ui->treeView->setModel(model);
    ui->treeView->setRootIndex(model->index("/home/waqar/"));
}
```

And in the `double_Clicked()` slot, use the `QModelIndex` to get the name of the folder you clicked on:

```
void MainWindow::on_treeView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    //displays the name of the folder you clicked on in the terminal
    qDebug () << index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();

   //get full path
  QString path = model->filePath(index)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the output is then just the name of the folder. But how would I get the full directory path? What is actually passed along inside the QModelIndex data? How can I find this kind of information?

Comment: alright I found out _index is of type QVariant which contians QString.. Kind of sucks because the files are named 2029, 2020 (years), and then 1-12 for months, 1-31 for days so I won't be able to figure out the full path, but I guess I'll just rename the files then, thanks!

Comment: You can use `QDateTime` for handling date / time based stuff if you want.

Comment: Check out https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum, `data` contains a lot of information and things. you can specify different roles to get different kinds of information from data(). You can also save your own information using Qt::Userrole. In the example above, I used DisplayRole, to get the display string, which happens to be folder name in our case.